# Query in oracle for periods of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following question, I have been trying to get the sum of the values ​​of a column in a certain period of time. For example, from May-2019 to May 2020, I have tried to implement a Join between the same entity but also a case but it has not been successful., for example I have this table:

```
  ---------------------------------
  | PRODUCT | VALUE | MONTH | YEAR |
  ---------------------------------
  | P1      | 10    |  2    | 2019 |
  | P1      |  5    |  3    | 2020 |
  | P1      |  22   |  4    | 2019 |
  | P1      |  4    |  2    | 2019 |
  | P2      |  4    |  2    | 2020 |
  | P2      |  7    |  4    | 2020 | 
  | P2      |  10   |  4    | 2020 |
```

And I wish I had this result

```
  -------------------
  | PRODUCT | VALUE |
  -------------------
  | P1      | 41    |
  | P2      | 21     |
```

Comment: Note that the value sums in your expected output are just taken over the entire table, _without_ filtering by the date.  Is that what you really want here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `date` from your table columns, Match it with your desired `date`, and use the `group by` as follows:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
 FROM YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE TO_DATE(YEAR || LPAD(MONTH,2,'0'), 'YYYYMM') 
         BETWEEN DATE '2019-05-01' AND DATE '2020-05-01'
GROUP BY PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to dates.  You could just use months:

```
select product, sum(value)
from t
where year * 12 + month > (2019 * 12 + 5) and
      year * 12 + month <= (2020 * 12 + 5)
group by product;
```

Or if you prefer:

```
where year * 100 + month > 201905 and
      year * 100 + month <= 202005
```

(These assume that you really want 12 months, not 13.)

The problem with this approach or using conversions to dates is that indexes cannot be used for filtering (although presumably arithmetic is slightly faster than date conversions).  That is a really good reason why you want the year/month as a date in a single column.  Oracle has pretty good indexing, so you might try:

```
where (year = 2019 and month > 5) or
      (year = 2020 and month <= 5)
```

On a large amount of data, Oracle should be smart enough to use an index (if it is reasonable for the query).

You could resolve this with a calculated column and an index on that column.